# Does injective continuous / holomorphic functions preserve winding number?

Tags: complex-analysis, homotopy-theory, winding-number

I am trying to find if the winding number is invariant to some transformations. I already know that it is invariant respect to translation, rotation and scaling. Also, it is not invariant respect to every continuous / holomorphic function since $z^n$ changes it. However, it is true that it is invariant with respect to homotopy. But I am not able to see if an injective function represents an homotopy. I would like to know if adding the conditions of continuity or holomorphism the invariance is true. Or if there exists a counterexample.